# How to prove that $\frac{(n^2+n)}{2n^2+n}$=O($\frac{\log_e n}{n}$) is True or False?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Supposing $u = \cfrac{(n^2+n)}{2n^2+n}$ and v = $\cfrac{\log_e n}{n}$
I've tried to do this question by finding out that $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\cfrac{u}{v})$ is undefined.

As the big $O$ notation need the $|\cfrac{u}{v}| < K$, where $K$ is some constant for all sufficiently large $n$. Doest finding out that the limit of it is undefined answer the question?

Thank you :)

Comment: Non-existent limit does not mean anything. $\sin(n) \in O(1)$ even though $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sin(n)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That limit is not undefined (in case $x=n$). In fact as $n\to+\infty$,
$$\frac{u(n)}{v(n)}=\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2+n}\cdot \frac{n}{\ln n}=\frac{n+1}{2n+1}\cdot \frac{n}{\ln n}\sim \frac{n}{2\ln n}\to +\infty$$
So your statement is FALSE.

Comment: So If I have proven that the $\frac{u(n)}{v(n)}$  is approaching +$\infty$ as n goes to $\infty$, than u(n) = O(v(n)) is False? and True for otherwise?

Comment: @Kupluk Jumityeh Actually I do not understand what  $x$ is in your notations. The answer is False as soon as $x=x(n)$ and $\lim_{n\to +\infty}x(n)=\infty$.

Comment: oh my god, i'm so sorry, it supposed to be $\frac{\log_e n}{n}$

Comment: @Kupluk Jumityeh That's OK. So the situation is clear now. Isn't it?

Comment: yes, but just to clarify, u(n) = O(v(n)) is true IF AND ONLY IF the limit of $\frac{u(n)}{v(n)}$ exist and not $\infty$

Comment: No, $u(n) = O(v(n))$ is true iff $\frac{u(n)}{v(n)}$ is bounded. It is not necessary that the limit exists. For example $(3+\sin(n))n\in O(n)$ because $2n\leq (3+\sin(n))n\leq  4n$.